# ¿Cómo dar nombre determinado a un archivo en bash?

Tags: linux

tengo una consulta sobre programación Bash. Debo realizar una búsqueda recursiva sobre un determinado directorio y extensión que paso por parámetro al script. A su vez, este debe crear un archivo en un directorio que se llama doc/ y el archivo en cuestión se debe llamar de la siguiente forma:

```
archivo-<extension>en<directorioBusqueda>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear un archivo con ese nombre en particular?

```
Aquí dejo mi código

#!/bin/bash

#
#Primero armamos los parámetros de la búsqueda y se los pasará por consola
#

DIRECTORIO=$1;**texto en negrita**
ARCHIVO=$2

#
#Si no nos pasa ningun parámetro el programa se cierra
#

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Necesito parámetros para ejecutarme."
   exit 1
elif [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
   echo "Solo necesito dos parámetros."
   exit 2
else
   echo "Cantidad de parámetros correcta."
fi


#
#Validamos la existencia del directorio y buscamos los archivos.
#

if [ -d $DIRECTORIO ]; then
   echo "El directorio existe y es válido"
   ( find $DIRECTORIO -type f -iname "$ARCHIVO" ) && 
   ( find $DIRECTORIO -type f -iname "$ARCHIVO" ) > $HOME/doc/"archivo1-<$ARCHIVO>en<$DIRECTORIO>"
else
   echo "No existe el directorio"
   exit 3
fi

exit 0
```

SALIDA:

la salida del archivo en la creación del archivo tiene el siguiente error:
/home/programacion/doc/archivo1-<*.sh>en: No existe el fichero o el directorio

Comment: Gracias por la edición del código, ahí si se entiende mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que no estas reasignando el en la variable ARCHIVO el valor de los ficheros que encuentras. Para ti, ARCHIVO es la expresión regular para que te busque todos los ficheros acabados en *.sh

Yo lo haría así

```
#!/bin/bash

#
#Primero armamos los parámetros de la búsqueda y se los pasará por consola
#

DIRECTORIO=$1
ARCHIVO=$2

#
#Si no nos pasa ningun parámetro el programa se cierra
#

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Necesito parámetros para ejecutarme."
   exit 1
elif [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
   echo "Solo necesito dos parámetros."
   exit 2
else
   echo "Cantidad de parámetros correcta."
fi


#
#Validamos la existencia del directorio y buscamos los archivos.
#

if [ -d $DIRECTORIO ]; then
   echo "El directorio existe y es válido"
   files=$(find $DIRECTORIO -type f -iname "$ARCHIVO")
   if [ ! -z $files ]; then
      echo "No he encontrado nada"
      exit 1
   else
      for i in files; do
         touch $(echo "$HOME/doc/archivo-<$i>en<$DIRECTORIO>")
      done
   fi
else
   echo "No existe el directorio"
   exit 3
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi versión, y prueba que funciona :

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Validar los parámetros de la búsqueda

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Use:  $0 <directorio>  <archivo>"
   exit 1
elif [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
   echo "Solo necesito dos parámetros."
   exit 2
fi

DIRECTORIO=$1
ARCHIVO=$2

#
#Validamos la existencia del directorio y buscamos los archivos.

if [ -d $DIRECTORIO ]; then
   echo "El directorio existe y es válido"
   files=$(find $DIRECTORIO -type f -iname "$ARCHIVO" -exec basename {} \;)
   if [ -z "$files" ]; then
      echo "No he encontrado nada"
      exit 1
   else
      mkdir -p $HOME/doc
      for i in $files; do
              touch $HOME/doc/archivo-\<$i\>en\<$DIRECTORIO\>
      done
   fi
else
   echo "No existe el directorio"
   exit 3
fi

exit 0
```

```
$ ./x   .   "*.a"
El directorio existe y es válido

$ ls -l $HOME/doc
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 hvillabl 1049089 0 ene. 14 15:51 'archivo-<a.a>en<.>'
-rw-r--r-- 1 hvillabl 1049089 0 ene. 14 15:51 'archivo-<b.a>en<.>'
-rw-r--r-- 1 hvillabl 1049089 0 ene. 14 15:51 'archivo-<c.a>en<.>'
-rw-r--r-- 1 hvillabl 1049089 0 ene. 14 15:51 'archivo-<d.a>en<.>'
```